# How to keep projects of previous blender versions when installing new versions?

Tags: versions

I have a **Blender version** 2.78 build for windows and would like to use the new 2.79 test build. I am unsure as to whether deleting the 2.78 version to install the 2.79 version will erase the projects on it.

Is there a way to do this without getting rid of the projects?

Comment: first you do not have to delete the old version to get the new one. But no all your blends are safe. (maybe the startup, userpref will get deleted if you used the install) but all your creations are perfectly safe.

Answer (score 1):

First off, reinstalling Blender won't delete any blend file.
Second, there is a portable version for each release, which means you don't necessarily have to uninstall anything and can have multiple versions at the same time. Moreover, the 2.79 RC1 only has a portable version, no installer yet. So in fact you can't even replace your 2.78 installation.

To use the portable version, unzip it and open Blender.exe, very simply.